# How to implement a decision matrix in java?

Tags: java

Given the matrix below, what would be a nice way of implementing it in Java?
I want to return the string message e.g. `"Possibly OK"` when the corresponding predicates are met for that position e.g. `pIndex = 4, volume = 1`.

[image: Decision Matrix]
I essentially have `5 * 5` conditions so that's `25` possibilities.

Here is the best I could come up with (there must be a neater, more maintainable way that's not a chunky if statement):

```
@Test
void decisionMakerTest() {
    String decision = DecisionMaker.makeDecision(4.0, 1.0);
    Assertions.assertEquals("Possibly OK", decision);
}
```

```
class DecisionMaker {

    private DecisionMaker() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Utility class");
    }

    private static List<Rule> ruleList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Rule(i -> (i <= 5), v -> (v <= -10), "Too Low"),
            new Rule(i -> (i <= 5), v -> (-10 < v && v <= -5), "Too Low"),
            new Rule(i -> (i <= 5), v -> (-5 < v && v < 2), "Possibly OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (i <= 5), v -> (2 <= v && v < 5), "Possibly OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (i <= 5), v -> (5 <= v), "Other - Investigate"),

            new Rule(i -> (5 < i && i <= 10), v -> (v <= -10), "Too Low"),
            new Rule(i -> (5 < i && i <= 10), v -> (-10 < v && v <= -5), "Possibly Too Low"),
            new Rule(i -> (5 < i && i <= 10), v -> (-5 < v && v < 2), "OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (5 < i && i <= 10), v -> (2 <= v && v < 5), "OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (5 < i && i <= 10), v -> (5 <= v), "Possibly Too High"),

            new Rule(i -> (10 < i && i < 90), v -> (v <= -10), "Possibly Too Low"),
            new Rule(i -> (10 < i && i < 90), v -> (-10 < v && v <= -5), "OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (10 < i && i < 90), v -> (-5 < v && v < 2), "OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (10 < i && i < 90), v -> (2 <= v && v < 5), "OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (10 < i && i < 90), v -> (5 <= v), "Possibly Too High"),

            new Rule(i -> (90 <= i && i < 95), v -> (v <= -10), "Possibly Too Low"),
            new Rule(i -> (90 <= i && i < 95), v -> (-10 < v && v <= -5), "OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (90 <= i && i < 95), v -> (-5 < v && v < 2), "OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (90 <= i && i < 95), v -> (2 <= v && v < 5), "Possibly Too High"),
            new Rule(i -> (90 <= i && i < 95), v -> (5 <= v), "Too High"),

            new Rule(i -> (95 <= i), v -> (v <= -10), "Other - Investigate"),
            new Rule(i -> (95 <= i), v -> (-10 < v && v <= -5), "Possibly OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (95 <= i), v -> (-5 < v && v < 2), "Possibly OK"),
            new Rule(i -> (95 <= i), v -> (2 <= v && v < 5), "Too High"),
            new Rule(i -> (95 <= i), v -> (5 <= v), "Too High")
    ));

    static String makeDecision(double pIndex, double volume) {
        for (Rule rule : ruleList) {
            if (rule.test(pIndex, volume)) {
                return rule.getDecision();
            }
        }

        return "Other - Investigate";
    }
}
```

```
class Rule {

    private DoublePredicate pIndexRule;
    private DoublePredicate volumeRule;
    private String decision;

    Rule(
            DoublePredicate pIndexRule, DoublePredicate volumeRule, String decision
    ) {
        this.pIndexRule = pIndexRule;
        this.volumeRule = volumeRule;
        this.decision = decision;
    }

    public boolean test(double pIndex, double volume) {
        return pIndexRule.test(pIndex) && volumeRule.test(volume);
    }

    String getDecision() {
        return decision;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have 25 conditions only and that is not going to change, what you currently have is enough ( it should be good ) but if your conditions are going to increase it is not maintainable anymore and you could consider something like [Drools](https://www.drools.org/) or because you have only two decision variables you could rather invent a good hash function that takes those two values and map onto a decision value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class DecisionMaker {
  static final List<DoublePredicate> P_INDEX_TEST = Arrays.asList(
        x -> x >  5.0,
        x -> x >  10.0,
        x -> x >= 90.0,
        x -> x >= 95.0
  );
  static final List<DoublePredicate> VOLUME_TEST = Arrays.asList(
        x -> x > -10.0,
        x -> x >  -5.0,
        x -> x >=  2.0,
        x -> x >=  5.0
  );
  static final String[][] TABLE = {
        {"Too Low",             "Too Low",          "Possibly OK", "Possibly OK",       "Other - Investigate"},
        {"Too Low",             "Possibly Too Low", "OK",          "OK",                "Possibly Too High"},
        {"Possibly Too Low",    "OK",               "OK",          "OK",                "Possibly Too High"},
        {"Possibly Too Low",    "OK",               "OK",          "Possibly Too High", "Too High"},
        {"Other - Investigate", "Possibly OK",      "Possibly OK", "Too High",          "Too High"},
  };

  static String makeDecision(double pIndex, double volume) {
    int row = (int) P_INDEX_TEST.stream().filter(p -> p.test(pIndex)).count();
    int col = (int) VOLUME_TEST .stream().filter(p -> p.test(volume)).count();
    return TABLE[row][col];
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's way neater than my approach.